# Excel Index Match with text string

Tags: excel-formula

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yLW91.png)I am trying to write a formula that will allow me to return a value based on it being matched with a short text string that is contained in a longer text string. Please see below. I would like the "Unit Time" column in the second table to retrieve that corresponding value from the first table by matching the shorter text string in the product column of the first table in the longer product name in the second table. Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Thanks

[excel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K3OxP.png)

Comment: Is it always trying to match the first two codes, or can the code be anywhere in the string?

Comment: If you need only the first five characters to match (i.e. `PD-DP`) you can `=VLOOKUP(LEFT(D2,5),...)`

Comment: @Taosique row 4 only has 4 characters.

Comment: I think that I would prefer to be able to do it assuming the text could be anywhere in the string

Answer (score 1):

If the product will always be XX-XX then you can use:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(Left(D2,5),A:A,0))
```

If the product can be more than 2 characters around the dash, then you'll have to use the Find() formula to get the position of the end of the product in col D instead of Left().

To account for row 4 as Scott pointed out:

```
=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(LEFT(D2,FIND("-",D2,4)-1),A:A,0))
```

This will find the second dash in the string and use the variable length for the Left() function.

Comment: Look at row 4, it does not follow that pattern.

Comment: I like your second formula.  I wish the OP would answer the questions.  Mine was a little more involved. `=INDEX(B:B,MATCH(LEFT(D2,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(D2,"-","}}}",2))-1),A:A,0))`  or `=VLOOKUP(LEFT(D2,FIND("}}}",SUBSTITUTE(D2,"-","}}}",2))-1),$A:$B,2,0)` This does not care about the pattern it will find the first second `-` regardless of how many characters in the first two.  But the question is what happens when the lookup in Column D matches perfectly?  Will that ever happen?  Too many questions and no feed back.

Comment: This works.  Thanks.  I wonder though if there is a way to do it without basing it on the second dash and using the actual text.  I can see situations in which I might need to go further than the second dash